# "No tests found in the class" is thrown when running tests in IntelliJ IDEA using TestNG framework

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I have a maven project, with testng framework.
I agree I might have played around with different JAVA versions, changing project level SDK's and stuff.
So after a while when I tried to run a test using testng annotation, it would give me "no tests found in the class "

After a while I got an error which had this text->"...-Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=...."

Answer (score 4):

So I performed below steps in IntelliJ and it was back to normal

```
 File -> Invalidate Caches -> Clear file system cache and local history -> invalidate and restart.
```